# What is the line code to call a var from another VC?

Tags: viewcontroller

I need to make an IF statement, and I need to check if one var from another vc is empty or not:

Ex:

```
if switch2?.isOn == true && **SecondViewController.myString2** != " "
          {
          let secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
              secondController.myString2 = "blabla"; ()
```

The thing is: this is not working because SecondViewController.myString2 is not the right way to call this var from the second VC.

It would be highly appreciated your comments.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! I guess it is swift code. Please add relevant tags to get attention of experts

Comment: ... also some example code might attract some attention too. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask